# How to sort an array in C++ and get the original index positions of the sorted elements?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have an array of numbers:

```
[66,43,642]
```

If I were to sort this array in ascending order, it would become:

```
[43,66,642]
```

Given **the original array**, I want to obtain an array of 1-indexed indices of its elements in the same order as the elements would appear in the sorted array, therefore:

```
[2,1,3]
```

Note: this without actually changing the order of elements in the original array.

Comment: Umm. I don't think we need custom iterators. The phrasing of the question is confusing, but it's clear to me that this is just sorting an array of indices, a garden-variety call to `std::sort` will do that.

Answer (score 2):

It is evident that you need to create an array of indices that will be sorted.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 66, 43, 642 };
    size_t i[std::size( a )];

    std::iota( std::begin( i ), std::end( i ), 0 );

    std::sort( std::begin( i ), std::end( i ),
        [&]( const auto &left, const auto &right )
        { return a[left] < a[right]; } );

    for (const auto index : i)
    {
        std::cout << index + 1 << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    for (const auto index : i)
    {
        std::cout << a[index] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
2 1 3
43 66 642
```

If your compiler does not support C++ 17 then instead of the function `std::size` you may use expression `sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a )`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a pair array and then sort it.

```
 pair<int,int> pair_arr[n];

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      pair_arr[i] = make_pair(arr[i], i);
  }
        
 sort(pair_arr, pair_arr + n);
```